# Anaconda Navigator - Looking for a resolution when I Launch Jupyter Notebook button but it fails with Exit Code 1 Error

Tags: anaconda3

[image: 1]

Problem: Anaconda app fails during Anaconda Navigator launch button for Jupyter Notebook fails with Exit code 1 error.

Expectation: Launch Jupyter Notebook button successfully

Please note the screen paste description for further details.  Having issue posting this comment and its says code is entered incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

Go to Environment Variables under System variables.

Under PATH , click Edit and add NEW:

C:\Windows\System32